# Permission denied for "go test" in jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, go, jenkins, testing, continuous-integration

currently I am trying to create a Pipeline in Jenkins to automatically deploy my go application into a docker container on my linux VM. There is no problem in building and deploying the application, but every time my test stage runs, i get a permission denied error:
[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXCl.png)

This is how my Jenkinsfile looks like (without checkout):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }
    tools {
        go 'go1.20.6'
    }
    environment {
        GO114MODULE = 'on'
        CGO_ENABLED = 0 
        GOPATH = "${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_ID}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'which go'
                sh 'go get .'
                sh 'go build'
            }
        }
       
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                withEnv(["PATH+GO=${GOPATH}/bin"]){
                    echo 'Running vetting'
                    sh 'go vet .'
                    echo 'Running test'
                    sh 'cd test && go test unit_test.go'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins has root rights and the template from the Jenkinsfile is from here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-build-and-test-of-go-application-with-jenkins-9f96879b5479

Already thank you for helping

Tests should run through as normal on my local machine.